# Cannot hit simple node web server hosted on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

Not able to hit my simple node web server hosted on an ubuntu EC2 in AWS.  But I can't see I've missed anything!  I've provided screen shots below within AWS - What am I missing?  Please help!.
Many thanks,

**Node code**

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 8080;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

**Command prompt**

```
$ node index.js
```

**Command prompt response**

```
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

**EC2 instance**

[image: ec2 settings]

**Security settings**

[image: security settings]

**Elastic IP settings**

[image]

**Browser**

```
http://"Public DNS (IPv4) value":8080/
```

**Update**

[image]

Comment: You've opened up port 80 in your security group.  What port is your node server using?

Comment: Yes, what dropdown value should I select to change the port number?  "HTTP" is fixed on 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select the type, select "Custom TCP Rule":

[image: Port Rules]

and enter 8080 in the port range field.

**EDIT**

However, that only gets you part of the way.  If you notice, your server is listening on the IP address `127.0.0.1`.  That means that it's not listen to the outside world, only `localhost`.  To access it outside of the server machine you'll need to change your code to:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 8080;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

The change is that you're now listening on "all interfaces" as compared to just localhost.

Comment: I've made that change but no difference, I've included the change in my original question as a screen shot.

Comment: That's very strange, I'm sure my other EC2 had the same node server code and it worked but thank you that got it working.

Comment: Did you have something like Apache or Nginix in front of the server, acting as a proxy?

Comment: I think I had a load balancer now you mention it (the EC2 load balancing/load balancers option)